# How to get files in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

I have to upload file on server through AJax request.
I have created that function and Its working on IE 10, 11 but unfortunately its now working on IE9.
 var file = inputTypeElmnt;
file.files[0];

file.files is not supported on IE 9.
what is the alternative for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution which involves the use of a hidden `iframe`, basically you set the target of a form to the `iframe` then submit the form.

```
var form = document.querySelector('#test');
form.addEventListener('change', change);
function change(event){
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.name = 'iframex';
  form.target = iframe.name;
    iframe.style.width = 0;
    iframe.style.height = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.addEventListener('load', load);
  form.submit();
}
function load(event){
  alert(this.contentWindow.document.body.textContent);  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/memc6qnq/1

or you could just use something like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload (which would probably be doing the same thing)

Comment: Thanks man. Its working.  :)
I just added 
 form.action = strUrl;
 form.method = "POST";